# Visual Studio 19 XAML Designer System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I started a new solution and added the template WPF App project to the solution. I can't get into the XAML Designer due to the error `System.ArgumentException` I keep getting. This is problem is consistend through all solutions.

What seemed to work for other people:

- Deleting a file called `Program` in `C:\`, I don't have that file and never had it tho I still have some leftovers when my system was in German but I don't think thats important
- changing the target to x86, recompiling, closing and reopening the window; tried this in combination with different build and compile profiles but also didn't work
- reinstallation of VS19; still not working
- using a VM with clean Windows 10 and clean installation of VS19; haven't tried but will not try because I don't want to develop part of my program in a VM
- deleting the shadowcache

My System and installation:

- Windows 10 Enterprise Build 18362 (Installation disk was in German, changed language to English)
- VS19 and other VS related programs are installed in their default location

Stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentException
An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Telemetry.VsTelemetryService.RegisterDesignerProcessSession(Int32 pid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.DesignerSessionTracker.RecordDesignerStart(Int32 processID, String isolationTargetIdentifier, String buildConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationDomainFactory isolationDomainFactory, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Update:

I've noticed that starting the Designer for the first time leads to another error:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationDomainFactory isolationDomainFactory, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationDomainFactory domainFactory, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating VS19 to the latest build (16.3.2) fixed the problem. My guess is that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#top-issues-fixed-in-visual-studio-2019-version-1631) fixed the issue.

Comment: This same issue happened with me. All of my projects exhibited the same error. But when I went to check the VS 2019 install, it turned out the last update had partially failed. I restarted the update and all was good. Whew.